# Making a Chrome extension to replace a single image

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

sorry if this has already been asked - I looked extensively, but can't find anything that seems to address it. Though it's quite possible it's been asked a dozen times already and the language used just went completely over my head. Which brings me to this: I'm not technologically stupid or anything, but as far as coding anything goes, that's another story entirely and I know virtually zero terminology regarding Chrome extensions. I just started googling about an hour ago.

Anyway, the question. I'm trying to make an extension to replace a single gif on a website I frequent. It's a loading image, so it appears on virtually every page, and it's just atrocious. The image is called (is that the right word?) by a script...rocket-script, I think it's called, which refers to it as ajax_loader, from browsing the page source? And the CSS stylesheet gave me the URL for the image.

So, here is the code I have, based on googling:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "name": "extensioname",
    "description": "extensiondescription",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["websiteitselfurl.com*","URLofimagetobeblocked.gif"],
            "js": ["part2.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

And then there's

**part2.js**

```
document.images[0].src = "replacementimage.gif";
document.images[0].height = "300";
document.images[0].width  = "300";
```

Obviously those aren't the actual URLs, but...
All this ends up doing is replacing an image on every webpage, regardless of where it is, with the replacement gif. And not even the loading image in question on the site I am trying to replace in the first place.
I've tried changing the values in the "matches" line to a few different things, including  at the end as in the example I found, and...that's literally all I can think to do.
I'd like to reiterate that I'm a complete know-nothing moron about this, so I apologize if it's already been asked, but I really cannot find an answer anywhere, and for the life of me I cannot get this to work myself and I'm out of ideas at this point. I registered here just to ask because I'm like ripping my hair out over it.

Any guidance whatsoever would be tremendously appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I would think there would be an extension that already does something like this. How about [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switcheroo-redirector/cnmciclhnghalnpfhhleggldniplelbg?hl=en). It has good reviews.

Comment: I found that earlier, and I'll give it a go if I can't figure this out, but I was kind of hoping I could find a way to make this work as a standalone extension thinking maybe if it went well I'd be encouraged to try to do other things with extensions and maybe create something useful to people one day. Good link though, thank you!

Comment: So your question is you want to replace an image in any site with a gif which is in your extension folder, am I right?

Comment: I don't know anything about developing chrome extensions but I think the problem is that you are replacing the first image element(`<img>`) on the webpage with your replacement gif, whatever the first image is. And your question suggests that the image is defined in a css file so it wouldn't be an image tag. You would have to change the css property of the element and you need to target that element somehow. Does it have a specific id or class?

Comment: Sorry, I was worried that was a bit unclear - I want to replace a specific image on a specific site with a different image. I'm hosting the different image on imgur.

Comment: Is the `id` of the element `ajax_loader`?

Comment: The id of the element is ajax_loader, yes.

Comment: ok, try something like this: `document.getElementById('ajax_loader').style.backgroundgroundImage = 'replacementimage.gif';` (this assumes it is a background image; it might not work). Actually this probably won't work because it wouldn't exist when it displays.

Comment: Could you please provide the imgur path for your gif?

Comment: Andrew - would I replace the line beginning with "matches" with that line you provided? Or add it after it? Haibara - http://i.imgur.com/Li7isRP.gif

Comment: Sorry I don't think that would work, it was just an idea. You would have replaced everything in part2.js with that line.

Comment: Let me know if you tried it and if it works or not.

Comment: No luck so far. It's stopped arbitrarily replacing images on every page I visit, but it's not replacing anything at this point.

Comment: If possible can you post the url to the website?

Comment: Don't laugh please, it's not at all what it sounds like - http://vampirefreaks.com

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are referring gif hosted in external site(imgur), you should use the full path of that image: `https://i.imgur.com/Li7isRP.gif`

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "name": "extensioname",
    "description": "extensiondescription",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://websiteitselfurl.com/*",     "https://websiteitselfurl.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

content.js

```
var ajax_loader = document.getElementById("ajax-loader");
ajax_loader.style.setProperty('background', 'url("https://i.imgur.com/Li7isRP.gif")', 'important');
// If needed, you could also change width/height of ajax_loader to better match the new image.
```

Comment: I think that's close; it's directly affecting the image I want to replace now. It's duplicating it (vertically) though, instead of replacing it.

Comment: @senorspaghetti, what do you mean duplicate?

Comment: Normally when a page is loading, it will display a single gif of a clock gear. With that extension running, it displays the clock gear gif twice - once in the normal position, and again what appears to be after a single linebreak.

Comment: @senorspaghetti, what's the element with id "ajax_loader"? An img tag or any else? Can I get it from vampirefreaks.com?

Comment: I found it here http://vampirefreaks.com/_style/main_style.css?2, from the source on pretty much any page there.

Comment: @senorspaghetti, for div element, you should change its background or background-image property, I notice the css is using background, so see updated answer.

Comment: Still zero impact. I'm beginning to think I may have just asked this while misunderstanding some really fundamental aspect of the whole thing and it's throwing off the very educated people trying to help me because of something I mistakenly assumed was right. If I upvote you guys' posts and delete the thread to avoid potentially wasting anyone's time further, do you still get karma for it?

Comment: @senorspaghetti, it doesn't matter. But I believe a better way would be clearing your thoughts and make the post easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I would throw in another possible avenue for a solution. Since you want to replace a gif that loads in dynamically, it might be better to just redirect the request rather than try to alter the page after it is called. Something using the [`webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) api would work well for this. For example:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "VF Sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A sample for VF gif replacement",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest","webRequestBlocking","http://vampirefreaks.com/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bgp.js"]
  }
}
```

**bgp.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details){
  return {redirectUrl:"http://i.imgur.com/Li7isRP.gif"};
},
{urls: ["http://vampirefreaks.com/_img/site/ajax-loader*"]},["blocking"]);
```